# SQL calculate percentage based on existing data in table and update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table as below with all the fields except percentage. Based on the total Number of cases I need to calculate percentage for each case id. For easy interpretation I choose numbers as below. So the total cases for all the caseids is 100, out of which case id as 35 cases so its percentage is 35. What script can I use to get those total percentage values and update in table accordingly.

```
CaseID NumHighCases NumMedCases NumLowCases TotalCases TotalPerc
1         10            20         5           35          35%
2         5              5          5          15          15%
3         8              12         20         40          40%
4         3               4          3         10          10%
```

Comment: Why even update the table? Why not calculate this on the fly each time you need it?

Comment: What's the SQL to achieve the above.  It appears you just need a `Total_cases / sum(total_cases) over (partition by null) as totalPerc` in the SQL to select the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TotalPerc = (TotalCases*100.0)/sum(TotalCases) over (partition by null)
```

Note the *100 is to add precision, otherwise an int/int will return an int.

Comment: I thought [2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) for window functions... but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry John, I had deleted my comment. I see, I figured doing this in one shot rather than doing two selects would of course be more efficient. I realized I was interpreting the question as OP having a static table with all of these pre-existing columns, whereas I assume your and xQbert's solution is with the understanding that OP is trying to compute this information during a `SELECT`, on-the-fly. Is that correct?

Comment: @xQbert I think you are correct.  It has been a while since 2008.  I dare you, ask me what I had for dinner last night  :)

Comment: @Santi OP specified "all the fields except percentage", so I just assumed that is the case

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I know how to handle you forward thinkers... What's for dinner... TONIGHT! :P

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. I'll have to get a bit more familiar with `partition`. Thanks!

Comment: @Santi Well worth your time to get comfortable with the window functions,  They are invaluable!

Comment: How do I up vote that comment more than once :P  It's black magic at first, but once you get comfortable saves soooo much coding and generally execution is just as fast or faster than what we could write ourselves.

Comment: @xQbert Pizza with crushed Oreos

Comment: @xQbert I'm sure you recall the days when we tied ourselves in knots to perform such functions... temp tables, sub-queries, conditional joins.  Kids these days got so it easy.

Comment: So true it's taken me some time to get use to the ease of this.  I'm still begging other developers to use these methods but they say it's too hard and those who come after to maintain will not understand as it's a too complex feature.... (then they come back to me when their solution is minutes in processing vs milliseconds when we use the window functions)  mmm Oreos...   Look over there! <snags an Oreo>

Comment: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses. This is the error I get when try to use your to update table.

Comment: @user1098028 How or where are you using it?.. Perhaps if you edit your question and post your query.  That will eliminate the assumptions

Comment: I just used in select instead of updating table that works fine for my scenario as well. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user1098028 Well done!  I knew you would figure it out  :)